# Fade out effect when my text appear css

Tags: css

I would like to make a text from my div class "fadeOut" to disappear after being displayed for 2 sec.

Is there a simple way to do that with a css transition ?

```
            $('#errMsg').append('<div class="fadeOut">Beware</div>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using jQuery

try this

```
$('#errMsg').append('<div class="fadeOut">Beware</div>').delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

If you need a pure CSS solution try this

```css
#errMsg {
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        opacity:0
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='errMsg'>This is will hide after 5 seconds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css transition property `transition-delay`:

```
.element {
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

Here is a list of applicable `transition` properties:

```
/* property name | duration | timing function | delay */
transition: all 4s ease-in-out 1s;
```

You can read more about transition delays here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Comment: Thanks but where to specify the opacity ?

Comment: If you want to change the opacity of the element with the transition then just set a starting and ending opacity on two different properties (default and hover, for instance), then specify `opacity` or `all` to target the opacity during the transition. I've updated the above to show this